# responsive alignment with bootstrap

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4, responsive-design

I need some help with bootstrap responsiveness. I placed four itens aligned to the right of an image (A title section and 3 itens). I already set up to run on large screens, but when running on small screens I'd like to keep just the title section on the right of the image and the other 3 itens drop bellow. Currently, all itens and the title goes down.

```css
@media (min-width: 576px) {
  img {
    width: 100%;
  }

  .title {
    text-align: left;
    width: 100%;
  }

  .item .item-icon {
    float: left;
    font-size: 40px;
    width: 50px;
    height: 50px;
  }

  .item .item-content {
    float: right;
    text-align: left;
  }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge" />
    <title>Document</title>

    <!-- fontawesome -->
    <script
      src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/24734ac872.js"
      crossorigin="anonymous"
    ></script>

    <!-- bootstrap -->
    <link
      rel="stylesheet"
      href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css"
    />

    <!-- style -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="container">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-6">
          <img src="http://placehold.it/300" />
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-6">
          <div class="row">
            <div class="title text-center">
              <h1>About me?</h1>
              <p>things about me...</p>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="row">
            <div class="item">
              <div class="item-icon">
                <i class="fas fa-heart"></i>
              </div>
              <div class="item-content">
                <h1>Thing 1</h1>
                <p>About thing 1...</p>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="row">
            <div class="item">
              <div class="item-icon">
                <i class="fas fa-heart"></i>
              </div>
              <div class="item-content">
                <h1>Thing 2</h1>
                <p>About thing 2...</p>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="row">
            <div class="item">
              <div class="item-icon">
                <i class="fas fa-heart"></i>
              </div>
              <div class="item-content">
                <h1>Thing 3</h1>
                <p>About thing 3...</p>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <!-- jquery -->
    <script
      src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.min.js"
      integrity="sha256-CSXorXvZcTkaix6Yvo6HppcZGetbYMGWSFlBw8HfCJo="
      crossorigin="anonymous"
    ></script>

    <!-- bootstrap -->
    <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

The result should be somthing like this:

[image]

Gif:

[image]

Thanks!

Comment: Haven't used bootstrap in a long while but I'd say, you are creating to many `<div class="row">`s, and if you make correct use of `<div class="col-*">` (align items with it) there wouldn't be a need for more CSS media queries.

Comment: I see. I've tried but with no success. How about grid layout?

Answer (score 0):

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge" />
    <title>Document</title>

    <!-- fontawesome -->
    <script
      src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/24734ac872.js"
      crossorigin="anonymous"
    ></script>

    <!-- bootstrap -->
    <link
      rel="stylesheet"
      href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css"
    />

    <!-- style -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
    <style>
        @media (min-width: 576px) {
  img {
    width: 100%;
  }

  .title {
    text-align:right;
    width: 100%;
  }

  .item .item-icon {
    float: left;
    font-size: 40px;
    width: 50px;
    height: 50px;
  }

  .item .item-content {
    float: right;
    text-align: left;
  }
}
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="container">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-6">
          <img src="http://placehold.it/300" />
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-6">
            <div class="title text-center">
              <h1>About me?</h1>
              <p>things about me...</p>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
          <div class="row col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
            <div class="item">
              <div class="item-icon">
                <i class="fas fa-heart"></i>
              </div>
              <div class="item-content">
                <h1>Thing 1</h1>
                <p>About thing 1...</p>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="row col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
            <div class="item">
              <div class="item-icon">
                <i class="fas fa-heart"></i>
              </div>
              <div class="item-content">
                <h1>Thing 2</h1>
                <p>About thing 2...</p>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="row col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
            <div class="item">
              <div class="item-icon">
                <i class="fas fa-heart"></i>
              </div>
              <div class="item-content">
                <h1>Thing 3</h1>
                <p>About thing 3...</p>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <!-- jquery -->
    <script
      src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.min.js"
      integrity="sha256-CSXorXvZcTkaix6Yvo6HppcZGetbYMGWSFlBw8HfCJo="
      crossorigin="anonymous"
    ></script>

    <!-- bootstrap -->
    <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Hi! Didn't work as expected pal. I'd like when open in small screens, 'about me' section stays at the right side of the image and the 3 items go bellow the image. When in bigger screens, all the text align to the right of the image. I posted a gif for better understanding.